# Python socket accept() does not accept a connection

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

A quite basic problem, but I can't find my mistake. I bascially used [this](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) tutorial code to implement my own client-server program: Client sends some data, the server displays it (instead of echoing data like in the tutorial)

The echoing tutorial code works, but my adjusted code to print data on the server doesn't. I added some delimiter mechanism to detect the entire message. My code:

Server.py:

```
class ThreadedServer:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        print("Server bound on Port "+str(port))

    def listen(self):
        self.sock.listen(5)
        while True:
            print("Waiting for incoming connections...")
            client, address = self.sock.accept()
            client.settimeout(60)
            print("Starting Working thread.")
            threading.Thread(target=self.listenToClientDelimiter, args=(client, address)).start()

    def listenToClientDelimiter(self, client, address):
        print("Connect to client "+address)
        length = None
        buffer = ""
        while True:
            data = client.recv(1024)
            print("Received raw data: "+str(data))
            if not data:
                break  # connection closed
            buffer += data
            while True:
                if length is None:
                    if LENGTH_DELIMITER not in buffer:
                        break  # delimiter not found, wait for next data package
                    length_str, _, buffer = buffer.partition(LENGTH_DELIMITER)
                    length = int(length_str)

                if len(buffer) < length:
                    break  # wait until full length got received before we proceed

                message = buffer[:length]
                buffer = buffer[length:]
                length = None
                # PROCESS MESSAGE HERE
                print(message)

        client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    ThreadedServer('', 65432).listen()
```

Client.py:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 65432))

    connect_user_cmd = "18:CONNECT_USER;Peter"
    print("Trying to send data: "+connect_user_cmd.decode())
    print(s.send(connect_user_cmd))
```

I run the server, then the client. The output from the server:

```
Server bound on Port 65432
Waiting for incoming connections...
```

As you see, I expect some log messages and of course my sent message. The client outputs this:

```
Trying to send data: 18:CONNECT_USER;Peter
21

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This gets outputted from the client even when I don't start the server. The weird thing is that the echoing part did indeed work. Could someone hint me into the right direction? Thank you!